# Will a single chestnut tree produce fruit without pollination partners?

Tags: pollination, nut-trees

I have a single horse chestnut tree which is about 3 years old - it's yet to flower or fruit which I think is quite normal but I am curious if it will produce conkers without any other chestnuts in the local area?

My horse chestnut is simply for ornament (and conkers are fun) but I would love to plant a sweet chestnut to eventually get edible nuts. I wondered if these two trees would be pollination partners?